# How set form input property to calculated global variable value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, setattribute

I'm trying to set the totalCost displayed on the form to what my javaScript function is calculating.  For some reason, it's not working when I try to set it to the calculated value, but it changes when I set it to a string.  How do I get the form value set to what I calculated? See comment indicating where field is that I'm trying to set with code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var totalCost;

       function getPrice(bookCost)
       {
          var shippingCostIndex;
          shippingCostIndex=document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
          var shippingCostOptions=document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
          var shipDestination;

          shipDestination=shippingCostOptions[shippingCostIndex].text
          alert("shipping Location:"+shippingCostOptions[shippingCostIndex].text);
          if(shipDestination=="Eastern")
          {
              totalCost = bookCost + Number(2);
              document.pikeForm.totalCost.setAttribute("value",totalCost); //**totalCost doesn't set it but "hello" sets the form value here
          }

       }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="pikeForm" id="pikeForm" action=".../form.pl" method="post">

<fieldset>
<legend>your location</legend>
<label >Please indicate your ship destination in US.<br>
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" size="3" >
   <option >Western</option>
   <option >Eastern</option>
   <option >Central</option>
</select>
</fieldset>

<input type="button" value="priceShipCalculator" onclick="getPrice(10)">
<br><br>

<fieldset>
<legend>order of Pike Book</legend>
<label for="pikeBook" >We will await your payment of $10 plus shipping and handling according to the above table for:<br>
   <input id="pikeBook" value="Pike">How to Fillet a Pike</input><br>
<label for="totalCost"> Book Cost:
   <input id="totalCost" name="totalCost" value="totalCost"></input> <!--**I want to set price to calculated price here-->
</fieldset>

</form>
</body>
```

I've looked at [setAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) online but it's not answering my question since I can set the value with a string but not with the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `document.pikeForm.totalCost.setAttribute("value",totalCost+"");`, `+""` converts your value into a string.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here, but first things first: the shortest, and correct way to set the value of an input field would be this:

```
document.pikeForm.totalCost.value = totalCost;//assuming all the name properties are correct
```

But I notice all kinds of weird constructions you use, probably in an attempt to avoid type-coercion oddities. For example:

```
totalCost = bookCost + Number(2);
```

Coercing a value to a given type can be done differently (and more easily):

```
totalCost = 2 + (+bookCost);//+varName coerces var's value to number
var asString = totalCost+'';//concatenate empty string, coerces to string
```

No need to call functions, let alone functions that double as constructors

You also have some odd markup:

```
<input id="totalCost" name="totalCost" value="totalCost"></input>
```

I suspect you meant this to be:

```
<input type='text' id='totalCost' name='totalCost' value='default value'>
<!-- optionally close this tag using XML-style /> as in: <input _attributes here_ /> -->
```

Other niggles include:

- Global variables are *evil*
- redundant DOM queries (`document.getElementById('mySelect')` twice in a row, why?)
- JS in markup is bad form
- No handling of errors, for example: no values selected

Be that as it may:

## [Basic fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/94EV3/)

And [here's an alternative approach](http://jsfiddle.net/LagVB/). It's slightly more complicated, but is unaffected by the issues I mentioned above (no globals, except for the function, no redundant DOM queries, no JS in markup, and error checking)

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments!  I'm just learning JavaScript so I'm trying to apply info from class.  The global variable is my idea.  I want to look at your alternative approach but it won't let me open it where I am.  I'll try looking later/elsewhere unless you know how to post the alternative here. I wish I could get rid of the editable input fields for what I'm calculating and setting. I had two DOM queries in a row that were similar because I was having trouble getting the shipping cost from my form without using the index applied to all the options that I retrieved.